# What is the folder picture_library on my Plesk panel on a site hosted at GoDaddy

Tags: godaddy, plesk

I have my website hosted with godaddy.

It's not even a month since I hosted with them.(*actually, the site itself isn't older than a month*)

When, I logged in to my Parallels Plesk, I saw a folder named **picture_library**

I tried to see what's inside that, but there was nothing. It came back even after I deleted it twice.

1. I didn't create a folder with that name, so its not in my code.
2. I didn't think my website, (*which is not even a month old*)  will attract hackers :)
3. There's little possibility of virus or something because, GoDaddy is the Market Leaders and I don't think that their servers will be vulnerable to such attacks.

My Actual Question:

Is it a virus or hacker and how to disable it?

Comment: Probably is some software from GoDaddy. You should ask them about it as they will know better than us.

Comment: Plesk (and cPanel) create all sorts of folders depending on what options you navigate in the control panels. You don't necessarily need to "activate" anything, simply browsing the CP can create folders on the filesystem! "GoDaddy are the Market Leaders" - [How I lost my $50,000 Twitter username](http://thenextweb.com/socialmedia/2014/01/29/lost-50000-twitter-username/#!xMGFq) - just saying.

Comment: @w3d that was awful ;) Are you the victim ?

Comment: @AmitJoki: No, not me, thankfully! In fact (bizarrely), I've just noticed the guy has gotten his Twitter username back! https://twitter.com/N

Comment: @AmitJoki This is one of the default directories automatically created when you add a new account in Plesk - it has nothing to do with GoDaddy, any host using Plesk will result in the same directories created like this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That folder is created by default when they set your account on that server.

You can make a search on your favourite search engine and you'll find many people talking about that.

So don't worry about it.

By the way, GoDaddy, and anybody else, doesn't matter the size or reputation, is vulnerable to attacks. But you are right thinking that they know who to protect themselves.

You can read [a few mentions of the picture_library on a search](https://www.google.com/search?q=plesk+%22picture_library%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aunofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=sb), how to remove it, why it's there, etc.

Comment: Guess what, this page appeared in the first and second and third place in google results !